# is there any way to find correlation with ax.scatter for multiple data frames

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, correlation

i've been trying to find correlation with ax scatter,the problem is i have multiple dataframes so everytime i try to do it KeyError always come out.do you have an idea to do it? Thank You!

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling

usd = pd.read_csv("data_usd.csv")
emas = pd.read_csv("emas_.csv")
minyak = pd.read_csv("minyak_brent.csv")
sawit = pd.read_csv("sawit.csv")
kcl = pd.read_csv("kcl.csv")
fosfat = pd.read_csv("fosfat.csv")


df1 = pd.DataFrame(usd)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(emas)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(minyak)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(sawit)
df5 = pd.DataFrame(kcl)
df6 = pd.DataFrame(fosfat)
df_col = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6], axis=1)
df2.columns = ['month_emas', 'price_emas', 'change_emas']
df3.columns = ['month_minyak', 'price_minyak', 'change_minyak']
df4.columns = ['month_sawit', 'price_sawit', 'change_sawit']
df5.columns = ['month_kcl', 'price_kcl', 'change_kcl']
df6.columns = ['month_fosfat', 'price_fosfat', 'change_fosfat']
df_col.columns
df_col.shape
df_col
df_col = df_col.set_index('Month')
df_col.head()
import numpy as np
df_col.corr()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,8))
ax.scatter(df1['Month', 'Average USD/IDR=', 'Min USD/IDR=', 'Max USD/IDR=','Nb of working days'], df2['month_emas', 'price_emas', 'change_emas'], df3['month_minyak', 'price_minyak', 'change_minyak'], df4['month_sawit', 'price_sawit', 'change_sawit'], df5['month_kcl', 'price_kcl', 'change_kcl'], df6['month_fosfat', 'price_fosfat', 'change_fosfat'])
plt.show()
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure(figsize=(14, 8))
sns.heatmap(df_col.corr())
plt.show()
```

here's the error
the error is always change,when i try to delete df1,df2 become the key error

[image: the error is always change,when i try to delete df1 values,df2 values become the key error]

Comment: Post the exact error please. It's unclear which key fails.

Comment: Done!  i edited it already

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with correlation or plotting but with the fact that your indexing syntax is wrong. The syntax is `df[key]`. If you input multiple keys like `df[a,b,c,d]`, then it assumes that `key=(a,b,c,d)` which is exactly the error you get. You can either merge all dataframes into a single table or call scatter separately for each dataframe (though I have no idea what you're trying to do with the indexing, if you require multi-indexing you can lookup the correct syntax).